# Angular2 : Drag Events Using Directives On Table Row Works Very Slow

Tags: drag-and-drop, angular, angular2-directives, slowdown, angular-dragdrop

I am implementing dragdrop functionality with the help of directives.

```
@Directive({
selector: '[Droppable]',
host:{
    '(dragenter)':'onDragEnter($event)',
    '(dragover)':'onDragOver($event)',
    '(dragleave)':'onDragLeave($event)',
    '(drop)':'onDrop($event)'
}
})
export class DragDropDirective {

@Input('Droppable') isDropable:boolean;

@Input() set doBoarderHighLight(decision:boolean) {
    this._doBoarderHighLight = decision;
    this._doBackgroundHighLight = !decision;
}

@Input() doBackgroundHighLight(decision:boolean) {
    this._doBackgroundHighLight = decision;
    this._doBoarderHighLight = !decision;
}

@Output() OnDrop = new EventEmitter(false);

_doBoarderHighLight:boolean = false;
_doBackgroundHighLight:boolean = true;
_isDropable:boolean = true;
el:ElementRef;

constructor(public _el:ElementRef) {
    this.el = _el;
}

onDragOver(e:any) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

onDragEnter(e:any) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (this._doBoarderHighLight) {
        this.el.nativeElement.addClass("drag-over");
        this.el.nativeElement.addClass("highlight-border");

    }
    else {
        this.el.nativeElement.addClass("drag-over");
        this.el.nativeElement.addClass("highlight-background");

    }
}

onDragLeave(e:any) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (this._doBoarderHighLight) {
        this.el.nativeElement.removeClass("drag-over");
        this.el.nativeElement.removeClass("highlight-border");
    }
    else {
        this.el.nativeElement.removeClass("drag-over");
        this.el.nativeElement.removeClass("highlight-background");
    }
}

onDrop(e:any) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    Utils.nextEventIfExist(e, this.OnDrop);
    if (this._doBoarderHighLight) {
        this.el.nativeElement.removeClass("drag-over");
        this.el.nativeElement.removeClass("highlight-border");
    }
    else {
        this.el.nativeElement.removeClass("drag-over");
        this.el.nativeElement.removeClass("highlight-background");
    }
}
}
```

And I am using the directive on  table rows,

```
<tbody *ngFor="let row of rows;#i = index">      
<tr [Droppable]="isDropableRow"   (OnDrop)="OnDropRow($event)" [ngClass]="{'row-data':true,'active':row.isSelected,'disabled-row':!isEnabled(row)}" (click)="onRowClick($event,row)">
```

The problem is that, the drag events fires very slowly, as you can see I've adding and removing classes to highlight the rows on dragEnter and DragLeave.

The thing I got is that the slowness is from angular2's zone js, may be the problem in my code or the problem in angular.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is caused by https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6311

There is already a PR https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/8761

Comment: I am using sync EventEmitter :@Output() OnDrop = new EventEmitter(false);                                                                                  And there is nothing related to EventEmitter for my eyes; the dragevents itself getting delayed.

Comment: I suspect `(dragover)` bindings also using `EventEmitter` behind the scene with default to `async`.

Comment: I had the same assumption    so I tried the following                                          ngOnInit() {
    this.el.nativeElement.addEventListener("dragenter", this.onDragEnter.bind(this));
    this.el.nativeElement.addEventListener("dragover", this.onDragOver.bind(this));
    this.el.nativeElement.addEventListener("dragleave", this.onDragLeave.bind(this));
    this.el.nativeElement.addEventListener("drop", this.onDrop.bind(this));
}

Comment: ngOnDestroy() {
    this.el.nativeElement.removeEventListener("dragenter");
    this.el.nativeElement.removeEventListener("dragover");
    this.el.nativeElement.removeEventListener("dragleave");
    this.el.nativeElement.removeEventListener("drop");
}

Comment: You could try `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` to avoid change detection being run after each event.

Comment: no differences. As I mentioned the issue is with zoneJS. Related To ChangeDetection

Comment: I will try that and Update.

Comment: No Changes @Günter Zöchbauer

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas.

Comment: I stumbled upon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756555/angular-2-drag-and-drop-directive-extremely-slow and this might give some ideas as well https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8804#issuecomment-221456326